# Checking value of Multiple Radio Buttons JQuery and showing the value in HTML using this example

Tags: jquery, button, radio-button

```
   //check selections
     $("input[type='button']").click(function(){

   // get the values of the radios here                                      
        var radioValue = $("input[name='q1']:checked").val();
        var answer = "Oxi Codine";

   //process    
        if(radioValue === answer){
            $("#question").text("Question: Which of the following is the most appropriate next step in management of this patient? Your are correct the answer is: " + radioValue + ".");

        }else{
            $("#question").text("Question: Which of the following is the most appropriate next step in management of this patient? You answered " + radioValue + " that is incorrect. The correct answer is " + answer + ".");


        }
     });
```

I have the radio group name as: "q1", "q2", "q3" I haven't been able to get it to loop through. It only works with one radio button group. **Also, each question has an answer that I need to show and check if it is correct.**

Comment: If I understand, what you are asking for is how to iterate through all the questions to review them right? If that's it, then I would put a wrapper div in each question-answers block. Then put the same class to all this divs, select the class with jquery and iterate over the wrapper divs selecting the answer and questions with the function `find` over the wrapper. Also you could put the answer in a `display:none`element inside each block

Comment: The questions are numbered don't think I want to separate the ordered list into three separate containers. What I am going for in the jsfiddle the first radio block works can I replicate that two more times so when the answer button is pressed it checks the answer for the following two questions and shows the answer/response for all three questions not just the first? I have tried if{...}if else{...}else{...} but that doesn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. thanks for the help. I guess I can add breaks in there to put each question and answer on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your markup just a bit, you can then store the values in there and process them.

Revised markup:

```
<li class="quest" data-answer="Cystic hygroma">
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function () {
        // get the values of the radios here 
        var radioValue = [{}];
        $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function (index) {
            radioValue[index] = {
                choice: $(this).val(),
                answer: $(this).parents('.quest').data("answer"),
                index: index
            };
        });

        //process   
        var i = 0;
        for (i; i < radioValue.length; i++) {
            var question = "Question: " + $(this).parents('.quest').eq(radioValue[i].index).text();
            if (radioValue[i].answer === radioValue[i].choice) {
                $("#question").text(question + "You're are correct the answer is: " + radioValue[i].answer + ".");
            } else {
                $("#question").text(question + " You answered " + radioValue[i].choice + " that is incorrect. The correct answer is " + radioValue[i].answer + ".");
            }
            $("#summary").show();
        }

    });
});
```

See the slightly revised here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/3pwdcsgx/6/

Note I only did the first one but you can use it as a pattern. I did nothing with regard to your posting your "answer" text - you will need to determine how you wish to handle that for subsequent text (right/wrong).  This does NOT check for unanswered questions if that is important also.

**EDIT** - re: no question comment

You are correct - I had it working but then made a modification that broke it.  One issue here is that the only way to get the "question" text in in the text of the #question node that gets replaced. SO, I would suggest that IF that is the desired functionality, you store the actual question in a data element and then use that as the text in the processed answer - since this is the only "view" I have of this data.

I updated the fiddle and put the question data in the object I created (from the .quest class parent element).  This IS a bit ugly with the overwrite of the #question element but it should give you some ideas to build upon, storing the question and correct answer as I have. https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/3pwdcsgx/9/

snip of important part:

```
   $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function (index) {
       radioValue[index] = {
           choice: $(this).val(),
           answer: $(this).parents('.quest').data("answer"),
           question: $(this).parents('.quest').data("question"),
           index: index
       };
    });
```

Updated markup from the first question:

```
<li class="quest" data-answer="Cystic hygroma" data-question="Which of the following abnormalities is illustrated in figure 1?">
```

Comment: Thanks for creating this example I will see if I can get it to show all three questions and answers.

Comment: Your script is not showing the question in the jfiddle

Comment: @JosephMarini - I updated the fiddle and pasted a snip of the part for the question.  Obviously this  architecture is not perfect but only an example to build from - since the "text" of the question is really up to you to determine here (include the options etc.) and I have NO idea of the correct answer(s).